# How to export and import from View in Drupal7?

Tags: views, importing-exporting

i have a view in my project. And i want to import and export the views in Excel format. How to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41615/how-to-export-data-from-drupal-to-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> ```
> CSV
> Microsoft XLS
> Microsoft DOC
> Basic TXT
> XML.
> ```